# Split cell on delimiter using formulas

Tags: excel, split

Is it possible (using formulas) to split a string (in cell A1) into it's component parts via a delimiter? Where the delimiter is always the same, the Initial string is always in 4 parts. But the lengths of those substrings vary.

```
Current Job - VARK06_16 - 099 - ABC1
```

Becomes

```
Current Job
VARK06_16
099
ABC1
```

in cells B1,C1,D1 & E1 respectively.

Comment: Do you have to use a formula or can you just use the `Text to Columns` button on the `Data` tab of the ribbon? Then select and transpose.

Comment: I was hoping to just use formulas, so I could copy & paste in col A, get the data chopped into chunks, & keep the excel file updated that way.

Comment: Is it ***always*** split by a `-`? and the `-` is not used in a string you want to keep?

Comment: Yes, the delimiter is always " - " and it's never used elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Put this formula in B1 and copy down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

[image]

if you want in the same row then change the ROW(1:1) to Column(A:A):

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),(Column(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

And drag accross.

Answer (score 2):

this is quite easy to do so long as you are willing to have one column of extra formulae, to locate the positions of your delimiters.
[image: here is a screenshot]

to work out the delimiter locs use find and the location of the previous value - so the equation in B4 is =FIND("-",A$2,B3+1)

to extract the sub-strings use MID and the values from the delimiter locs columns. So the equation in C4 is =MID(A$2,B3+2,B4-B3-2)

There will be other ways to do this but this works.