# Split cell by delimited values formula (excel)

Tags: excel-formula

I had a similar question to the poster here and tried using the formula provided: [Split cell on delimiter using formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055688/split-cell-on-delimiter-using-formulas/38056589)

In my case, I have a spreadsheet with large text strings containing up to 50 distinct values per cell, delimited by "|". The format is "Product Category 1 > Product 1 | Product Category 2 > Product 2 | ..." etc.

If possible, I'd like to figure out how to extract values into a column formulaically.

The formula "=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"|",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))" (A1 contains the string) + drag & fill seemed to work perfectly, until I attempted to use it on a larger string which gives me a #VALUE! error. Through some experimentation I discovered that the formula will only error out if the string contains greater than 999 total characters.

I don't quite understand how ROW(1:1)*999+1 works as a positional indicator for the MID function, but it does seem to work up to a point. Raising the 999 threshold doesn't seem to make any difference. I've tried every possible combination of increasing the 999 values up to 2000 without success.

I thought the issue might be a hard character limit using the MID or SUBSTITUTE functions but I haven't had any luck finding info to back that up. If any of you brilliant folks wouldn't mind explaining to me what I'm missing, or if you have a more elegant solution for me, I would be much obliged.

Edit: Following @Euler's Disgraced Stepchild 's suggestion, a similar error occurs with >2 delimiters in the cell reference.

Thank you,
Patrick
[image: Formula view]

[image: Cell reference view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the newest version of Excel, you can use `FILTERXML`. The structure is something like:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML(
"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(cell_reference, "|", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"))
```

If you don't have the newest version, you can use the built in Text-To-Columns function. Simply select the range of cells, and go Data->Text-to-Columns->Next->Other->"|"->Next->Select location of new columns->Finish

EDIT: This won't work if the text string contains "&". To avoid that, use `SUBSTITUTE` to first replace the character with another one that doesn't appear in the string (for example, I choose "!") and then resubstitute in the correct character after using `FILTERXML`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(
FILTERXML("<t><s>"&
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(T17, "&", "!"), "|", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s")),
 "!", "&")
```

[image]

Comment: Sidenote to FILTERXML is that it only works on Windows computers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am operating in the latest version of excel on a Windows PC. I tried your formula and it is also producing a #VALUE! error if any more than three delimiters exist in the cell reference. Do you know of any work-around to accommodate up to 50? I was hoping to create a template with lookups that can build a table based on a single reference value without having to use Text-to-Columns and transpose repeatedly.

Comment: @sonofcarty12 It should work for large amounts of delimiters. See my edit for a picture of it working with 6, just as an example

Comment: @Euler's Disgraced Stepchild Added photos to my OP. You can see the formula working with only two delimiters in the reference cell (2nd row), but once a third delimiter is added (5th row) the formula errors out. Could there be something else in the referenced cell producing the error? (see bottom pic)

Comment: @sonofcarty12 Didn't realize your string might contain "&". See my edit for a workaround

Comment: It works! Thank you thank you @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild for the quick resolution :)